# Sandboxed solution; social tags?

Tags: sandbox-solution, sharepoint-online, social

I want to create a webpart to retrieve some of the social tags a user has used. This has to run in SharePoint Online ie a sandboxed solution. I have code which does the same, but already the first line uses SPServiceContext which isn't available in the sandbox:

[MSDN: SPServiceContext Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spservicecontext.aspx)

So I was wondering if it's even possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandbox does not allow the Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.dll so it will not be straight forward to access the termstore or social tags.

Hovewer, you can use SPQuery to access the values in a Managed MetaData column.